# Why are my errors showing up beside my control and in the validation control summary?

Tags: asp.net, validation

Why are my errors showing up beside my control and in the validation control summary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default if you have a [`ValidationSummary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.requiredfieldvalidator(v=vs.110).aspx) control, the error message shows in both places. If you want the error message to only show in the `ValidationSummary`, then set the `Display` property in your validation control to `None`.

From the [BaseValidator.Display Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basevalidator.display(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
None    The validation message is never displayed inline.
Static  Space for the validation message is allocated in the page layout.
Dynamic Space for the validation message is dynamically added to the page if validation fails.
```

Comment: In the future please cite your sources.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely because you did not set

```
Display="None"
```

in your validation control.  By setting `Display` to `None` you are indicating that you do not want the error message to appear in the place of the validation control itself, only in the validation summary.